# How can I convert/parse a chess .pgn file to a JSON file suitable for d3.js node tree

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, tree

I've racked my brain, and tried for weeks, but through php scripts, chesscanvas, and python scripts, cannot conqure this problem. 
I want to build a D3.js tree from a chess variation tree.

Chess is recorded by software as PGN. It's hiarchical in regards to variations, and almost like a JSON file in itself, save that the D3.js tree needs each move nested to draw out the tree.

Here is what a .PGN looks like in essence, with variations, or branches added

[PGN structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVaU6.jpg)

The PGN file shows the structure, of the file, but when you copy and paste it out, the text reader sees this...and this is what the code would see when it parsed it.

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 (3... Nf6 {- Berlin Defense} 4. O-O (4. d3 {Like
all of the d3 lines, the eval is equal} 4... Bc5 (4... Nd4 5. Nxd4 exd4 6.
O-O c6 7. Bc4 d5 8. exd5 cxd5 9. Bb5+ Bd7 10. Bxd7+ Qxd7 11. Re1+ Kd8 (11... Be7
12. Bf4 O-O 13. Nd2 Rae8) 12. Bg5 Rc8 13. Nd2 Bb4 14. a3 Ba5)) 4... Nxe4 {- Open
Variation} (4... d6 {Improved Steinitz Defence} 5. d4 Bd7 (5... exd4) (5... Nxe4
{Rarely played and not mainline, but plausible before 2000 due to tactical
nature and no "immediate" crushing reply.} 6. d5 a6 (6... Bd7 7. dxc6 bxc6 8.
Bc4 d5 9. Nxe5 dxc4 10. Qf3) 7. Bd3 Nc5 8. dxc6 bxc6 9. Nc3) 6. Nc3 Be7 (6...
exd4 7. Nxd4) 7. Re1) (4... a6 5. Bxc6 dxc6 6. Nxe5 Bd6 (6... Qd4) (6... Nxe4 7.
Re1 Qd4 8. Nf3 {+3.4}) 7. Nf3) 5. d4 Nd6 (5... Be7 6. Qe2 Nd6 7. Bxc6 bxc6 8.
dxe5 Nf5 9. Qe4 g6 (9... Nh4 10. Nxh4 Bxh4 11. Qg4 g6 12. Bh6) 10. c4 O-O 11.
Nc3) (5... exd4 {Riga Variation} 6. Re1 d5 7. Nxd4 {+0.81} 7... Qf6 (7... Bd7 8.
f3 Nxd4 9. Bxd7+ Kxd7 10. fxe4 Qh4 11. g3 Qf6 12. Rf1 (12. c3 Nf3+ 13. Kh1
Nxe1 {And all Options lead to hell.} 14. Qxe1 Qf3+ 15. Kg1 Bc5+)
12... Qe5 13. Nc3 Bc5 14. Kh1 (14. Be3 Kc8 15. Rxf7) 14... f5 15. Bf4) 8. f3 Bc5
9. Bxc6+ bxc6 10. c3 Bf5 11. Be3 O-O 12. fxe4 {+2.54, and the aggression is
dealt with} 12... Bxe4 13. Nd2 Rfe8) 6. Bxc6 dxc6 (6... bxc6 7. dxe5) 7. dxe5
```

and so forth....

Each move inside of a parenthesis is the first move of a variation, which each move is a child of each prior, but that whole variation is a child of only that one move.

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4.Ba4

   Ruy Lopez - Root
   e4
    -child
     e5
      -child
        Nf3
          -child
             Nc6
               -child
                  Bb5
                    -child
                       a6

Now when games branch off, or in the case that instead of one clear move, the side of multiple they choose from, each leading to a different game, each branch is a child of that one node, but siblings to each other - as follows

```
Ruy Lopez - Root
e4
 -child
  e5
   -child
     Nf3
       -child
          Nc6
            -child
               Bb5
                 -children
                    |a6
                    |Nf6
     siblings       |d6
                    |f5
                    |Bc4
```

And each of thsoe variations continue on as the initial game did before. Making a new move from anything other than the head of a variation implicitly creates a new variation. A hiarchy tree. There is a main line - everything outside of parenthesis, that is the top line. I don't know if that helps or not. In tree form, that should be the very top branches when expanded.

If at this point everytime ( is encountered, when that is doesn't meet another ) if there are any new ( encountererd - all variations inside close before the main one does, it could basically say everything each ( is a child varation of the prior parent move, and stops when it meets a ")"

I can't recall, you guys would know, it was called "Recursive" something and is well known to programming. My explainations are probably superfolous.

If at encountering { it can say "I see a bracket, everything inside is a string comment, and I want to take that and put it as  - "text" : "everything in bracket" - under the move, it would be immensely incredible.

Here is the goal,

http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~mjschwei/chesstreed3/20/

I can build the JSON file by hand, but it has proven too cumbersome to do so for this to be pragmatic. I will need a parser.

I need to turn the PGN information above, into at least this...

```
{
   "name" : "Ruy Lopez",
   "children" : [
      {
         "name" : "e4",
         "children" : [
            {
               "name" : "e5",
               "children" : [
                  {
                     "name" : "Nf3",
                     "children" : [
                        {
                           "name" : "Nc6",
                           "children" : [
                              {
                                 "name" : "Bb5",
                                 "children" : [
                                    {
                                       "name" : "a6",
                                       "children" : [
                                          {
                                             "name" : "Ba4",
                                             "children" : [
                                                {
                                                   "name" : "Nf6",
                                                   "children" : [
                                                      {
                                                         "name" : "O-O",
                                                         "children" : [
                                                            {
                                                               "name" : "Be7",
                                                               "children" : [
                                                                  {
                                                                     "
```

Where at Variations, instead  of children the moves would be siblings, and each succeeding move sequence thereafter would be children to that variation.

Ideally, the goal would be this..

```
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "e4",
      "move": "1",
      "text": "The Open Game",
      "fen": "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR",
      "side": "white",
      "nodecolor": "GhostWhite",
      "textcolor": "DarkSlateGrey",
      "variation": "Open Game",
      "type": "normal",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "e5",
          "move": "1",
          "text": "E4 is met with the symmetrical e5, indicating the liklihood of a sharp game",
          "fen": "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR",
          "side": "black",
          "nodecolor": "DarkSlateGrey",
          "textcolor": "white",
          "variation": "Open Game",
          "type": "normal",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Nf3",
              "move": "1",
              "text": "Open Game",
              "fen": "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R",
              "side": "white",
              "nodecolor": "GhostWhite",
              "textcolor": "DarkSlateGrey",
              "variation": "Open Game",
              "type": "normal",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Nc6",
                  "move": "1",
                  "text": "Open Game",
                  "fen": "r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R",
                  "side": "black",
                  "nodecolor": "DarkSlateGrey",
                  "textcolor": "white",
                  "variation": "Open Game",
                  "type": "normal",
```

So I can make this..

Well it won't let me post more than two links.. so I can't show the result I want. But, it's a d3.js tree that branches off at variations, and each node continues until the next variation, where a new branch occurs.

I've worked as a Photographer, 3D Modeler, lighting and rendering artist for the past 12 years. I hadn't seen Javascript since the Bush administration. When I saw the expandable tree, I fell in love, and knew it would be amazing to have a chess repertoire built out like that. I gave it a hell of a go, and got farther than I thought I could. I know many of these questions must seem stupid or annoying. But I've worked out the whole tree, chessboard, sending from the D3.js tree to the board, and comments to the comment box all myself. This I could not do. This, I had to have help. It is my second question, I don't want to make anyone mad by sounding ignorant....I just don't want to give up on this. Can anyone help?

Comment: From what I can tell you'll need to make your own parser

Comment: That appears to be the conclusion I have come up with as well. See, there are parsers out there for PGN, even PGN to Json. But, they won't put it in the d3.js format. I've tried Chesscanvas, which came the closest, but breaks around some of the variations. LiChess has their whole source code up, and so does DHTMLchess, but no luck there either. I'm in a pickle it looks like. Wondering if there is a relatively understandable way to write this thing.

Comment: What's a short example of one of the variations that break it

Comment: Perhaps you can use one of the PGN to JSON parsers you've found, and then convert that to the requisite d3 format?

Comment: No doubt about it. I got so close doing just that.. The chess parser found here

https://github.com/tomgp/chess-canvas/blob/master/node/old/generate_d3_basic_tree.js

Lets me convert .csv into Json. So I open MindGenius, and make something like this...

http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~mjschwei/chesstreed3/27/MindMap.JPG

which I convert to a .csv file, from which I can get my d3.tree Json file. Going from MindGenius to .csv then to Json might help me learn the opening, but limits the amount of data I have time to go through.